# Lebesgue measure of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Calculate Lebesgue measure of subset of $[0, 1]$, that got it first unit in decimal presentation surrounded by zeros. For example: 0,(...no units...)010(anything can be here)

Let's look at first possibility. $0,010...$ and we can choose any number like this in $[0.010, 0.011]$. Measure of this is $0.001$.
Then we got 0,_010....., [0,_010 0,_011], measure is $0.0001$.
So in total we got $0.001+0.0001+0.00001+...=0.00(1)$.
Is my solution right? I'm not sure in picking such numbers, what if in some iteration $0,....010$, we'll get a unit before 010?

**Update**:
I forgot about different combinations of ${0,2,3,...,9}$.
Accounting this in first itertation we got $10^{-3}$, second $9*10^{-4}$, third $9^{2}*10^{-5}$, etc... $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 9^{n}10^{-n-3}=0.001*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (9/10)^{n}=0.001*10=0.01$

Comment: What about the other numerals: 2,3,4,5,...?

Comment: @zoli you want to say that i got to calc all combinations of {0,2,..9} before 010?

Comment: I get a measure of 11/900.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet can you tell me how did you get it?

Comment: It is a union of pair-wise disjoint intervals $I_1,I_2,I_3,$.... Interval $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ where $a_n=10^{(-1-n))}$ and $b_n=a_n+10^{(-2-n)}$. ... I may have made an error in the arithmetic for the measure, as  I did it mentally.